# Scraping Data from booking with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

hope you're doing well !
So i'm trying to scrape data from Booking (name of Hotel , room ..) , i run the code it's work but i don't get the data in the excel file, the data file is empty !

This is my code :

```
# Create an Extractor by reading from the YAML file
e = Extractor.from_yaml_file('C:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Bureau/booking-hotel-scraper-master/booking.yml')

def scrape(url):    
    headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'DNT': '1',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        # You may want to change the user agent if you get blocked
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.113 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',

        'Referer': 'https://www.booking.com/index.en-gb.html',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    }
     # Download the page using requests
    print("Downloading %s"%url)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # Pass the HTML of the page and create 
    return e.extract(r.text,base_url=url)

with open("C:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Bureau/booking-hotel-scraper-master/urls.txt",'r') as urllist, open('C:/Users/pc/OneDrive/Bureau/booking-hotel-scraper-master/data.csv','w') as outfile:
    fieldnames = [
        "name",
        "location",
        "price",
        "price_for",
        "room_type",
        "beds",
        "rating",
        "rating_title",
        "number_of_ratings",
        "url"
    ]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writeheader()
    for url in urllist.readlines():
        data = scrape(url) 
        if data and data['hotels'] is not None:
            for h in data["hotels"]:
                writer.writerow(h)
```

And this is the result in the excel file :
[image]

There is no error in mycode it's only about how to get this data.

The booking.yml :

[image]

Comment: Have you insert `print` statements to show exactly what `scrape(url)` is returning?  Remember that you're using `DictWriter`, so it's going to expect every row to be a dictionary.  It's can't just be a list of items.

Comment: @TimRoberts it's returning `{'hotels': None} `

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you get `scrape()`. Second you could  use `print()` to see what you get in `r.text` . maybe you get warning for bots/scrits - maybe it asks you to resolve `Captcha` or it asks you turn on `JavaScript`. As I remeber `Booking.com` may use `JavaScript` to add elements but `requests` can't run `JavaScript`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`